# No Session found for current thread hibernate transactions by aop xml style

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions, persistence, h2

I use Spring MVC. I have a problem with trigger my service --> dao method from jsp page. When I ask for jsp in a browser it shows me this:

```
  2013-07-19 07:55:32,385 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/web/]>
2013-07-19 07:55:32,387 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - <Looking up handler method for path />
2013-07-19 07:55:32,388 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - <Did not find handler method for [/]>
2013-07-19 07:55:32,388 WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - <No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'>
2013-07-19 07:55:32,388 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <Successfully completed request>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,889 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/web/input]>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,889 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - <Looking up handler method for path /input>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,891 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] - <Returning handler method [public java.lang.String edu.demidov.web.MainController.inputForm(edu.demidov.web.FormBackingObjectInput,org.springframework.ui.Model)]>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,891 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'mainController'>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,891 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <Last-Modified value for [/web/input] is: -1>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,903 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] - <Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String edu.demidov.web.MainController.inputForm(edu.demidov.web.FormBackingObjectInput,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,905 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver] - <Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String edu.demidov.web.MainController.inputForm(edu.demidov.web.FormBackingObjectInput,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,906 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] - <Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String edu.demidov.web.MainController.inputForm(edu.demidov.web.FormBackingObjectInput,org.springframework.ui.Model)]: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread>
2013-07-19 07:55:41,907 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] - <Could not complete request>
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:988)
    at edu.demidov.dao.EducationWebDaoImpl.fetchAllInstitutionNames(EducationWebDaoImpl.java:161)
    at edu.demidov.service.EducationWebServiceImpl.fetchAllInstitutionNamesService(EducationWebServiceImpl.java:82)
    at edu.demidov.web.MainController.prepareModelNames(MainController.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.invokeModelAttributeMethods(ModelFactory.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory.initModel(ModelFactory.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:722)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I think the problem is with my xml application configuration. I read here that this type of problem occurs because Transactions not on properate place, not on Service layer, for me it seems like on proper just I use aop style to provide Transactions

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"> <!-- Using and configuring C3P0 proxy -->
        <property name="driverClass"><value>org.h2.Driver</value></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>jdbc:h2:/home/vadim/workspace-sts/h2/EDUCATION</value></property>
        <property name="user"><value>sa</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value></value></property>
        <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>3</value></property> <!-- Number of Connections a pool will try to acquire upon startup -->
        <property name="minPoolSize"><value>1</value></property> <!-- Minimum connection pool size -->
        <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>20</value></property> <!-- Max connection pool size -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge"><value>3600</value></property> <!-- Set max connection age to 1 hour, after it will release -->
        <property name="maxIdleTime"><value>600</value></property> <!-- 10 minutes connection can stay unused before be discarded -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout"><value>240000</value></property> <!-- Each what time check for unused connections -->
        </bean>

    <!-- Declare Hibernate transaction manager. Realization of PlatformTransactionManager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref ="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:advice  id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="fetch*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>    
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="eduWebPointcuts" expression="execution(* edu.demidov.service.EducationWebServiceImpl.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="eduWebPointcuts"/> 
    </aop:config>

    <!-- Looks for specific annotation configuration in this packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.demidov.dao, edu.demidov.service"/>

    <!-- Declare annotation configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Build sessionFactory annotation base configuration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref ="dataSource"/> <!-- Injecting datasource C3P0 to Hibernate sessionFactory datasource -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="edu.demidov.dto"/> <!-- Package will be scanned for entity classes -->

        <property name="hibernateProperties">   <!-- Configuring properties -->
            <props> 

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop> <!-- Put dialect for particular database to use queries to this DB -->
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>


                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</prop> <!-- Same to minPoolSize -->
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop> <!--Same to maxPoolSize -->
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">600</prop> <!-- Same to maxIdleTime -->
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">5</prop> <!-- Set number of cached statements used often -->

                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>  <!-- Sets a maximum "depth" for the outer join fetch tree for single-ended associations (one-to-one, many-to-one) -->
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">30</prop> <!-- Declare how many records will get from database in one package -->
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">15</prop> <!-- When it's a lot of queries in short time passed to database this put queries in one batch and send them to database -->
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

            </props>
       </property> <!-- End of configuration hibernateProperties -->

    </bean> <!-- End of configuring org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean -->
```

My

```
 <aop:pointcut id="eduWebPointcuts" expression="execution(*
 edu.demidov.service.EducationWebServiceImpl.*(..))"/>
```

is definitely where pointcut should execute, on each method of  EducationWebServiceImpl class.

What my be problem???

If you need here is my dao implementation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<String> fetchAllInstitutionNames() {        
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct institution.nameOfInstitution from InstitutionInForm institution").list();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<String> fetchAllInstitutionTypes() {        
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct institutionType.typeOfInstitution from InstitutionTypeInForm institutionType").list();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Date> fetchAllDates() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select distinct newDate.particularDate from FormDate newDate").list();
    }
```

My jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="fboiAttributes" action="add" method="post">

<table align="center">

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDate.particularDate"/> <form:select path="formDate.particularDate"> <form:options items="${listOfDates}"/> </form:select> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="institutions.nameOfInstitution"/> <form:select path="institutions.nameOfInstitution"> <form:options items="${listOfNames}"/> </form:select> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="institutionType.typeOfInstitution"/> <form:select path="institutionType.typeOfInstitution"> <form:options items="${listOfTypes}"/> </form:select> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.daySchedule"/> <form:input path="formDescription.daySchedule"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.workScheduale"/> <form:input path="formDescription.workScheduale"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.rotation"/> <form:input path="formDescription.rotation"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.numberOfKids"/> <form:input path="formDescription.numberOfKids"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.kidsUnder3YearsOld"/> <form:input path="formDescription.kidsUnder3YearsOld"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.kidsUpper3YearsOld"/> <form:input path="formDescription.kidsUpper3YearsOld"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.kidsGoSchoolDate"/> <form:input path="formDescription.kidsGoSchoolDate"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <form:label path="formDescription.kidsGoSchoolNumber"/> <form:input path="formDescription.kidsGoSchoolNumber"/> </td></tr>

<tr><td> <input type="submit"/> </td></tr>

</table>

</form:form>
```

I want to say, that this jsp page during rendering trigger dao methods to fetch some data from database for user to choose.

My MainController:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainController.class);


    @Autowired
    private EducationWebServiceImpl educationWebServiceImpl;


    @ModelAttribute("listOfDates") 
    public List<Date> prepareModelDate() {      
        List<Date> listOfDates = educationWebServiceImpl.fetchAllDatesService();
        return listOfDates;     
    }

    @ModelAttribute("listOfNames")
    public List<String> prepareModelNames() {       
        List<String> listOfNames = educationWebServiceImpl.fetchAllInstitutionNamesService();
        return listOfNames;     
    }

    @ModelAttribute("listOfTypes")
    public List<String> prepareModelTypes() {       
        List<String> listOfTypes = educationWebServiceImpl.fetchAllInstitutionTypesService();
        return listOfTypes;     
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/input", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String inputForm(FormBackingObjectInput fboi, Model model) {         
        model.addAttribute("fboiAttributes", fboi);         
        return "input";
    }
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/classes directory. Goes first -->
    <beans:bean id="xlsviewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    <beans:property name="basename" value="views"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean id="jspviewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="/resources/locale/messages"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.demidov.web, edu.demidov.service, edu.demidov.dao" />
```

Comment: Could you show us your jsp code snippet?

Comment: Yes sir. I added my jsp page

Comment: Does it work if you remove the transactional advices?

Comment: yes sir I tried just right now. It's same with transaction annotations and without them... We need to think The problem is that form main method works fine but from controller not.

Comment: Given the stack trace, there is no transaction interceptor applied on your web service. Show us how you get an instance of this web service in MainController.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your replay.. A add a new stack exception with log4j  preference  and code inside of MainController. I hope it's help. Thank you

Comment: I think I found the problem: you're redefining (by component-scanning) the DAO and service beans in your servlet-context.xml, instead of reusing those that are already defined (also by component-scanning) in the main application.xml file. Make sure to only scan web-specific components in the servlet.xml file.

Comment: Sir, I tried it too... One thing I did not tried is to delete component scanning form app-context and leave all packages component scanning in servlet-context, but this is doesn't help also. I have same error. Hm?? If it would be so easy I would solve it by myself, but it's not. And I'm asking you for help me.

Comment: So, you tried to only scan the web package in servlet.xml? What did happen? What is printed in the logs when you deploy and start this app?

Comment: Sir... I solved it with your help... As you can see in my MainController I'm trying to have instance on EducationWebServiceImpl, on my Service implementation NOT on Service interface, so that was first problem I found. Second, Yes I had previously package scanning declarations like you suggested to me, but after when I face this problem I changed it in different variations and already got lost what is right way.  So we solved it!!Thank you. And just tell me why we need to have separate package scanning in app-context and servlet-context?

Comment: Because, the servlet context inherits from the main application context. By re-scanning them in the child context, you redefine the beans (A bit like if, in a Java subclass, you had a field with the same name and type as a protected field in the base class)